# How can I add a css rule to a dynamically created element in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css

Is it possible to add css to a specific dynamically created div in jquery? I want to add an overlay to a specific div but trying to find a way to pass the id from the dynamically created div to the jquery function in order to only add the CSS rule to that specific div, is becoming a task for me. When I click on the div it adds the overlay to all of them. 
Thanks for your time and here is my code.

```
foreach($selectedPhotoResult as $rowSelect){
    if($counter % 3 === 1){
        echo '</div><div class="row">';
    }
        echo'
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center picContainer">
            <a class="overlayPicHL" data-overlayPicID-id="'.$row['ad_id'].'"><div class="price" style="position:absolute;top:0px;;right:15px;z-index:98;height:50px;width:50px;border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);"><i class="fa fa-eye" style="font-size:25px;color:#ffffff;position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;"></i></div></a>
                <div class="well photoControlsMain pht-brd-cl">
                    <a class="mainImageProfile" style="display:block;" data-userMain-id="'.$row['ad_user'].'" data-pic-id="'.$row['ad_photo_thumb'].'">
                        <div class="imageOverlayStyle">
                            Something here
                        </div>
                        <figure>                                                        
                           <img src="'.$row['ad_photo_thumb'].'" class="img-responsive imageSizingGallery imageProfileStyleSmall" style="object-fit: contain;" width="100%" alt=""/>

                        <div class="photoControlsMainImage">
                            <p style="z-index:9999;">
                        <span class="text-prt-und-bl usernameIndexPos">'.ucwords($row['industryName']).'</span>
                        <span class="adRateIndexPos">$'.$row['ad_rate'].'/hr</span>
         ';

    if($userfile->member_is_loggedin()){    
        echo'<a class="userMsgID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#msgUserModal" data-userSenduserID-id="'.$rowSelect['user_id'].'" data-userSend-id="'.$rowSelect['industryName'].'" data-username-modal="'.ucwords($rowSelect['industryName']).'"><span class="commentIcoPos"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i></span></a>';
            if($favList->rowCount() > 0){                                           
                foreach($favListResult as $rowFav){
                    if($rowFav['user_fav_id'] == $user_id){
                            echo'<span class="heartIcoPosRed adUnFav" data-unfav-id="'.$rowFav['fav_id'].'"><a><i class="fa fa-heart heartIcoRedColor"></i></a></span></a>';
                            }                                       
                    }   
            }else{
                echo'<span class="heartIcoPos adFav" data-userFav-id="'.$user_id.'" data-fav-id="'.$row['ad_id'].'"><a class="heartIcoWhite"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></span></a>';
            }   
                echo city($row['ad_city']);
        }else{                                          
            echo'</a>
                <a class="loginDisplayHeader" style="display:none;"><span class="commentIcoPos"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i></span></a>
                <a class="loginDisplayHeaderFull" id="loginFormShowHeader"><span class="commentIcoPos"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i></span></a>
                <a class="loginDisplayHeader" style="display:none;"><span class="heartIcoPos heartIcoWhite"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></span></a>
                <a class="loginDisplayHeaderFull" id="loginFormShowHeader"><span class="heartIcoPos heartIcoWhite"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></span></a>
                ';

                echo city($row['ad_city']);
                }

            $likes = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(likes) as likeCount
                FROM 
                    likes
                WHERE
                    user_accept_id = :adUserId                                  
                ");
                $likes->bindParam(":adUserId", $adUserId);
                $likes->execute();
                $likesFetch = $likes->fetchAll();                                       
                if($likes->rowCount() > 0){
                    foreach($likesFetch as $rowLikes){

                        echo'<span class="userLikeBtnLG">'.thousandsCurrencyFormat($rowLikes['likeCount']).' Likes <i class="fa fa fa-thumbs-o-up thbsUPND"></i></span>';

                            }
                        }
                    echo'</p>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
 </div>                                             
 '; 
}
```

Here is the jquery code so far

```
   $(".overlayPicHL").on("click", function() {
     const imageOverlayStyle = 
     $(this.nextElementSibling).find('.imageOverlayStyle');
     $(imageOverlayStyle).css({
     backgroundColor: 'yellow'
     });
   });
```

And this is the CSS for the overlay item

```
.imageOverlayStyle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

It's a simple overlay transition, I just need to figure out how to add this overlay to a specific div that is pulled from the database...dynamically created. I have searched for a solution for a while now with no such luck yet.

Comment: use event delegation as `$(document).on("click", "selector", function() {...});`

Comment: appreciate the help @DevsiOdedra, I tried your way but for some reason it does not want to fire on my end. If I just use $(".imageOverlayStyle").css({"height":"100%"}); then it displays on all of them but if I use your $(this).next solution it does not fire the css rule

Comment: so try `$(this).next().css..`  it will work

Comment: Yeah for some reason this.next does not want to work. :(  When I remove $(this).next and just have my original code $(".imageOverlayStyle").css({"height":"100%"}); then it fires the image overlay on all of the dynamic pics but when I use $(this).next nothing fires. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.imageOverlayStyle` you want to target is a child of the next sibling of the clicked `.overlayPicHL`, so use `nextElementSibling` and `[0]`:

```js
$(".overlayPicHL").on("click", function() {
  const imageOverlayStyle = $(this.nextElementSibling).find('.imageOverlayStyle');
  $(imageOverlayStyle).css({
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center picContainer">
  <a class="overlayPicHL" data-overlayPicID-id="'.$row['ad_id'].'">overlayPicHL
    <div class="price"><i class="fa fa-eye" style="font-size:25px;color:#ffffff;position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;"></i></div>
  </a>
  <div class="well photoControlsMain pht-brd-cl">
    <a class="mainImageProfile" style="display:block;" data-userMain-id="'.$row['ad_user'].'" data-pic-id="'.$row['ad_photo_thumb'].'">
      <div class="imageOverlayStyle">
        Something here
      </div>
      <figure>
        <img src="'.$row['ad_photo_thumb'].'" class="img-responsive imageSizingGallery imageProfileStyleSmall" style="object-fit: contain;" width="100%" alt="" />

        <div class="photoControlsMainImage">
          <p style="z-index:9999;">
            <span class="text-prt-und-bl usernameIndexPos">usernameIndexPos</span>
            <span class="adRateIndexPos">adrate</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center picContainer">
  <a class="overlayPicHL" data-overlayPicID-id="'.$row['ad_id'].'">overlayPicHL
    <div class="price"><i class="fa fa-eye" style="font-size:25px;color:#ffffff;position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;"></i></div>
  </a>
  <div class="well photoControlsMain pht-brd-cl">
    <a class="mainImageProfile" style="display:block;" data-userMain-id="'.$row['ad_user'].'" data-pic-id="'.$row['ad_photo_thumb'].'">
      <div class="imageOverlayStyle">
        Something here
      </div>
      <figure>
        <img src="'.$row['ad_photo_thumb'].'" class="img-responsive imageSizingGallery imageProfileStyleSmall" style="object-fit: contain;" width="100%" alt="" />

        <div class="photoControlsMainImage">
          <p style="z-index:9999;">
            <span class="text-prt-und-bl usernameIndexPos">usernameIndexPos</span>
            <span class="adRateIndexPos">adrate</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Solution @CertainPerformance, I tried your solution but it did not add the css rule. When I use $(".imageOverlayStyle").css({"height":"100%"}); it adds the style to all of the elements but when I added your code nothing would display. :(

Comment: The `backgroundColor: yellow` in the snippet is just an example to show that the code is working as desired. Of course, you have to change it to use the actual CSS you want there.

Comment: I tried to run your code using my css({"height":"100%"}) but still would not display the overlay. When I run my original code it adds the css but to all of the dynamicallly displayed images. Would there be some other reason why it will not add the css rule to that specific div?

Comment: Any console errors? As you can see by the live snippet, given the HTML provided in the question, the code in the answer appears to be working. If it doesn't work for you, it sounds like the HTML given in the question is not your *actual* HTML structure?

Comment: yeah I saw that your code was adding the proper styles when fired here in the code snippet, but when I ran it in my environment, it would not fire the css rule and display the overlay on any of the divs. I updated my code with some more of what I am working with around that overlay.  thanks

Comment: Now, the `mainImageProfile` you want to select is a child of the next sibling div, not the sibling itself. Use `.nextElementSibling.children[0];`. (Best to make sure the code in the question matches the code you're using when posting the question)

Comment: yes that is definitely what I need for it. But I need it to add the style rule to the "imageOverlayStyle", not the "mainImageProfile" class. Do I need to go deeper is there a children of children option? grandchild perhaps?  :)

Comment: If it's more than one level deep, use `.find` instead

Comment: BOOM...You got it on the money, i will update my question with the answer!!  Thanks a million @ CertainPerformance. I hope this helps plenty of others.

Answer (score 0):

Add the rules to a stylesheet so that they are automatically applied to the newly created elements.
Chain the css() method when you create your elements: $('') . appendTo(document. ...
Create a new stylesheet dynamically: $("").

```
$('<img id="newImage" src="text.jpg"/>')
.appendTo(document.body)
.css(style);
```

Create a new stylesheet dynamically:

```
$("<style>").text("#myNewEl { width:40px; height:35px; }").appendTo("head");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find `class` in entire document and add `css`, you can use `next()` if you want it to add to only `next(`) div

```js
$(document).on("click", ".overlayPicHL", function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-overlayPicID-id");
    $(this).next(".imageOverlayStyle").css({"height":"100%"}); //<-this is the css I want to add to the specific div when the icon has been clicked
});
```

```css
.imageOverlayStyle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a class="overlayPicHL" data-overlayPicID-id="'.$row['ad_id'].'">

<div class="price" style="position:absolute;top:0px;;right:15px;z-index:98;height:50px;width:50px;border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);"><i class="fa fa-eye" style="font-size:25px;color:#ffffff;position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;"></i></div></a>
<div class="imageOverlayStyle" id="imgOvrlayID" data-imgOvly-id="'.$row['ad_id'].'">
    Something here
</div>
```

Comment: @Stuckfornow can you post you html where having multiple blogs and divs

Comment: I added some more of the code to give you a little more insight into what might be going on. Thanks for your time.

Comment: yes but it incomplete, just add complete div like start `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center picContainer">` and upto end of that div